# Two Actions Performed When Pressing Submit on Signup Form: Need Specific Results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I would like help with adding code that will make the following happen: When my 'Submit' button is clicked (on signup form after subscriber enters email addr & name) signup page will reload (in same tab) with my website homepage url replacing form page.

At present, with the code I have, after 'Submit' is clicked the subscriber data goes to my autoresponder (this is working fine) and simultaneously after 'Submit' is clicked a Confirmation Page opens in a new tab (& I like this feature). As a novice at coding, I didn't know how much of my signup form code I should post here and/or which parts of the html/javascript would be needed for you to see what is currently going on. I have researched this topic extensively here on stackoverflow and found no solution that fits my exact situation. I think I may need to use AJAX in this application, but I will need to learn it.

Thanks for responding. All help is greatly appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitIt(form) {
var checkEmail = "@.";
var checkStr = form.rm_email.value;
var EmailValid = false;
var EmailAt = false;
var EmailPeriod = false;
var bad = "";
for (i = 0;  i < checkStr.length;  i++)
{
     ch = checkStr.charAt(i);
     for (j = 0;  j < checkEmail.length;  j++)
     {
        if (ch == checkEmail.charAt(j) && ch == "@")
        EmailAt = true;
        if (ch == checkEmail.charAt(j) && ch == ".")
           EmailPeriod = true;
          if (EmailAt && EmailPeriod)
                  break;
          if (j == checkEmail.length)
                  break;
        }
      if (EmailAt && EmailPeriod)
      {
            EmailValid = true;
            break;
        }
}
if (!EmailValid)
{
bad = bad + "\n    Please enter a valid Email Address.";
}
if (form.rm_first_name.value == "") {
bad = bad + "\n    First name is required";
}
if (bad != "") {alert("Please fill in the following fields:"+bad +"\n"); return (false);}
return (true);
}
</script>
<!--END OF JAVASCRIPT-->
<form name="signup" method="post" onSubmit="return submitIt(this);" action="https://go.reachmail.net/libraries/form_wizard/process_subscribe.asp" target="_blank" >
Email address<br />
<input type="text" id="rm_email" name="rm_email" />
<br />
First name<br />
<input type="text" id="rm_first_name" name="rm_first_name" />
<br />
<input type="hidden" name="my_type" value="3" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="15519">
<input type="hidden" name="list_name" value="XLIST_04F220B4A5C511E580D902BFAC100114">
<input type="hidden" name="list_id" value="900493">
<input type="hidden" name="el_list" value="email,first_name">
<input type="hidden" name="page_confirm" value="http://wc9007.wix.com/wade#!testoptinconf/n12yi">
<input type="hidden" name="list_fromname" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="list_fromemail" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="list_subject" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="opt_in_method" value="double" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: can you please post the code so I have something to work off?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the form HTML code?

One thing you can do is add:

```
header("Location: <YOUR HOMEPAGE URL>");
```

to the end of the script that runs after form submission (i.e. the script at the action= in your form html).

Thanks for posting your HTML code.  I can see that the action is:

```
https://go.reachmail.net/libraries/form_wizard/process_subscribe.asp
```

It looks like you do not have access to edit that process_subscribe.asp script.  Thus, you will need to POST to that URL with your form data and then redirect the page via JavaScript.

First, change your line which reads:

```
<form name="signup" method="post" onSubmit="return submitIt(this);     action="https://go.reachmail.net/libraries/form_wizard/process_subscribe.asp"     target="_blank" >
```

to

```
<form name="signup" method="post" action="https://go.reachmail.net/libraries/form_wizard/process_subscribe.asp" target="_blank" >
```

Then, add this to the top of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var frm = $('#signup');
frm.submit(function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            window.location.href = "<YOUR HOMEPAGE URL HERE>";

        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I posted the form HTML code as you requested. Your answer is still giving me trouble. I could post all the code as it is not much more. Maybe then you can direct me as to where EXACTLY to add your 'header...' suggestion. Any other ideas? Thank you!

Comment: You would need to add the header() call to the top of https://go.reachmail.net/libraries/form_wizard/process_subscribe.asp as that is where the form POSTs to.  Do you have access to edit that script?  Since it has an .asp extension and you are asking for PHP help, and looking at https://go.reachmail.net/, it looks like that URL belongs to a third party service.  If you do not have access to edit that script, I will create another answer with an alternative.  Let me know!

Comment: Hi Tim. Thanks for hanging in on my problem. Yes, ReachMail is a third party service and now I see what you mean. I do not have access to edit their script. I only have a section of code that I added to my site that they gave me for the subscriber data to be handled by them. Your alternative is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Gotcha!  Yes, I realized this 100% after I posted my last comment :/  If the solution is successful, please accept the answer -- if not, let me know and we'll work it out.

Comment: Awesome, Tim! I'm trying it now. One question though...Would you like to see the other code I do have access to? For example...

Comment: It couldn't hurt to see what the submitIt() function does.

Comment: I am new to the stackoverflow platform and some of my posts are not exact. I am going to add ALL the additional code so you can see what is going on. Thanks again for your help! Hang on...

Comment: Before you go ahead and do that, have you tried the answer I've posted already?

Comment: Need details... what does "without success" mean -- did you try to work on a bit after trying my answer?

Comment: Hi Tim. Before ever posting my question here I did extensive research trying to learn how to make my form page redirect to my homepage after submit. I am at my wit's end with how to proceed. I am at the mercy of your expertise and other stackoverflow members. With that being said, I honestly don't know what else to do besides rely on help on this site. I follow suggestions here to the "T". Other tweaking attempts of my own have been fruitless and left me frustrated. Thanks again for all you and others are doing.

Comment: Gotcha -- After changing the <form> line and adding the <script>, what errors, if any, are you seeing?  What exactly is happening/not happening.  I need details to assist as I cannot see what is happening over the internet.

Comment: Hi Tim. Happy New Year, btw. Nothing different is happening. Absolutely nothing. That's why there is nothing to report.